# invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]| (beginner)

Tags: c++, string, integer, atoi

When I try to compile my code this error pops out:

```
invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'
```

My task is to write a program that calculates the sum of numbers with odd index.

Please don't roast me (I'm learning how to code in c++), and give some tips how to fix it and get my code working.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string text;
    cin >> text;

    int len = text.length(), sum = 0, number = 0, a = 0;

    for (int i = len; i > 0; i++) {
        a = text[i];
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            number = atoi(a);
            sum = sum + number;
        }
    }
    cout << sum;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That error directed you to a certain line of your code where the problem is.  Do you see that?  Checking that is a good habit to form.

Comment: You got off on the wrong foot when you chose `string`. (You are almost certainly overthinking this; you need a sum, a number, and an index.)

Comment: `atoi` accepts c-string not an integer. So you can't feed `a` to it.

Comment: As answers come in, I notice a BIG issue that no one has mentioned regarding `for (int i = len; i > 0; i++)`.  I think you would be doing yourself a **huge favor** if you made a _much simpler_ program that works, and then slowly made your program more complex.

Comment: Creating a [mre] is not only a requirement for questions seeking debugging help, but also it is a useful learning tool. If you can isolate the problem down to `int main() { int a = 0; int number = atoi(a); return 0; }`, then you eliminate a lot of noise and preconceptions, leaving little space for a bug to hide.

Comment: Please don't invalidate all these answers by changing your question.  If you have a new question, please **ask a new question**.

Comment: Asking for *"some tips how to [...] get my code working"* covers numerous errors and is thus too broad for a Stack Overflow question. The site intends to be a repository to help others with the same problem. To support this goal, there is a limitation of one question per question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop is incorrect because at the first try it starts at out of range index and increases farther. here :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string text;
    cin >> text;

    int len = text.length(), sum = 0, number = 0, a = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       a = text[i];
       if (i % 2 == 1) {
            number = a - '0';
            sum = sum + number;
        }
    }
    cout << sum;

    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`atoi` is a function for converting a string to an integer, but `a` is a character not a string. That's why you have the error.

Replace `atoi(a);` with `a - '0'`. That's a formula for converting a digit character to its integer value.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues. The most obvious:

```
number = atoi(a);
```

atoi expects a const char *, but a is an int.

Note that it would help if you listed which line produces the error message.

Without trying it, I think you can get rid of the atoi() and just do:

```
sum += a - '0';
```

The other choice would be to make a into a string and use text.subst() to just get a single character, then you could do:

```
sum += atoi (a.c_str());
```

or

```
sum += stoi(a);
```

In programming, there are always a dozen of ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to extract functions. This will do your task without converting to string.

```cpp
int sumOfDigitsInEvenPos(int x, int base = 10) {
    x = std::abs(x);
    int sum = 0;
    while (x) {
       sum += x % base;
       x /= base * base;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more than few mistakes :

1. starting with declaring 'a' as int.
2. in Your for loop you are starting with length which should be
   length-1.
3. In for loop again you are using i++ which should be i-- or start with i=0;
4. When you are getting number why you are taking string as input
   taking as int/long should be more convient.
5. atoi accepts char * not int

try out below code it should solve your problem

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string text;
cin>>text;

int len= text.length();
cout<<len<<endl;
int sum=0,number=0;
char a;


for(int i=len-1;i>0;i--)
{
     a=text[i];
    if(i%2==1)
    {   number= (int)a;
        sum = sum+number;
    }

}
cout<<sum;

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to check return code of atoi function, because string consists non only of numeric values.
And length returns size of string, for example 5, but symbols iterates from 0 to 4. text[4] - final symbol.

Comment: The poster is complaining about a compiler error, not a runtime problem.